# Magento - problem sending email through an action

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have a basic module that accepts form data on the frontend and saves to a database.

What I'm also looking to do is to send an email if the data has been saved successfully.

I'd like the email to be sent to the store owner:

I have done the following to try and get this to work:

app/code/local/Aero/Catalogrequest/etc/config.xml

```
<template>
  <email>
    <request_brochure_email translate="label" module="Aero_Catalogrequest">
      <label>Request a brochure</label>
        <file>request_brochure.html</file>
          <type>html</type>
    </request_brochure_email>
</email>
</template>
```

and

```
<default>
  <Aero_Catalogrequest>
    <sendemail>
      <template>request_brochure_email</template>
    </sendemail>
  </Aero_Catalogrequest>
</default>
```

I have created a template file in: app/locale/en_US/template/email/request_brochure.html

```
   <p>
     {{var data.fname}}
   </p>
```

And this is my postAction in my IndexController.php

```
public function postAction()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ( $post ) {
        $request = Mage::getModel('catalogrequest/catalogrequest');
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $data['time_added'] = now();
        $data['country'] = $data['country_id'];
        $data['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $data['fname'] = ucwords($data['fname']);
        $data['lname'] = ucwords($data['lname']);
        $data['address1'] = ucwords(str_replace(",", " ",$data['address1']));
        $data['address2'] = ucwords(str_replace(",", " ",$data['address2']));
        $data['city'] = ucwords($data['city']);
        if(empty($data['region'])){
            $data['state'] = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load($data['state'])->getCode();
        } else {
            $data['state'] = $data['region'];
        }
            $postObject = new Varien_Object();
            $postObject->setData($post);

        // Validate
        if(!$errors = $request->validate($data)){
            MAGE::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($errors);
        }


        // Add to database
        try {
            $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SAMPLE_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $data)
                );

            if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            $request->setData($data)->save();
            MAGE::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('<h2>Thank you</h3> You can expect to receive your catalogue in 10-14 days.o. '));

            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/thanks');

        } catch(Exception $e){
            MAGE::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Sorry, we\'ve had some trouble saving your request');
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

    }
    return;
}
```

When submitting my form, data isn't sent to the email address that I have configured in the admin

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any error messages? Can you capture $e->getMessage() and post it here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to set a subject, otherwise you won't pass:

```
public function isValidForSend()
{
    return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')
        && $this->getSenderName()
        && $this->getSenderEmail()
        && $this->getTemplateSubject();
}
```

(Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template)

So, in your email template, add: `<!--@subject The subject of email @-->`

Hope that helps

Comment: Ok I have added the missing config in my email template. The problem is, the actual form fields in the email message are all returning as 'array' and not the actual input that I posted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to make it work, I had to replace:

```
array('data' => $data)
```

with

```
array('data' => $postObject)
```

All sends perfectly now!

Thanks all